# android Cannot display google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

hi to all I am trying to import some source codes to test displaying pin on Google Maps and dragging them .. Although the import to eclipse is successful and I can run them on my device the maps does not show up.. Is it about api key issue ? Do I need to generate new api keys to display them ? I got stuck can anybody help..

here is the projects that I've import

[first one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/%22First%20One%22)

[second one](http://www.ankitkedia.com/2012/01/08/drag-drop-pin-on-map-for-your-android-application/)

also the source code of second link here.

```
   public class rescue extends MapActivity {


private LocationManager myLocationManager;
private LocationListener myLocationListener;

private MapView myMapView;
private MapController myMapController;
private String provider;
private MyLocationOverlay me=null;


private int defaultLat =(int)(51.51216124955517); 
private int defaultLong =(int)(-0.1373291015625);

private GeoPoint defaultGeoPint = new GeoPoint(defaultLat,defaultLong);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rescue);

    setCurrentLocation();
   }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

private void setCurrentLocation()
{
  myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.rescueMapView);
  myMapView.setTraffic(true);
  ///myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

  myMapController = myMapView.getController();
  myMapController.setZoom(16); //Fixed Zoom Level

  myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

  try
  {
  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
  provider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

  Location location = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

  myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
          provider,
    0,
    0,
    myLocationListener);

  Location lastLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 

      if(lastLocation != null)
      {
          int lastLocLat =(int)(lastLocation.getLatitude()*1000000); 
          int lastLocLong =(int)(lastLocation.getLongitude()*1000000);
          //Get the current location in start-up
          GeoPoint initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(lastLocLat,lastLocLong);
          CenterLocatio(initGeoPoint);
      }
      else
      {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Location Services Disabled")
                 .setMessage("The location service on the device are disabled, your location is not able to be found, please call AXA uding the button below to be rescued")
                 .setCancelable(false)
                 .setPositiveButton("Drop pin", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          //do things
                         CenterLocatio(defaultGeoPint);
                     }
                 });
          builder.create().show();
      }
  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
    // TODO: handle exception


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String toasttext = e.getMessage();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toasttext, duration);
        toast.show();
  }
}

private void CenterLocatio(GeoPoint centerGeoPoint)
 {
    myMapView.getOverlays().clear();
  myMapController.animateTo(centerGeoPoint);
  Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

    int lat = centerGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6();
    int lon = centerGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6();

    double lat1 = centerGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;

    double lon1 = centerGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

    ArrayList<Double> passing = new ArrayList<Double>();
    passing.add(lat1);
    passing.add(lon1);

    Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
    ReverseGeocodeLookupTask task = new ReverseGeocodeLookupTask();
    task.applicationContext = context;
    task.activityContext = rescue.this; 
    task.execute(passing);

    myMapView.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker,lat, lon ));

    me=new MyLocationOverlay(this, myMapView);
    myMapView.getOverlays().add(me);

 };

 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

     @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(
        (int)(argLocation.getLatitude()*1000000),
        (int)(argLocation.getLongitude()*1000000));

       //CenterLocatio(myGeoPoint);
      }

      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

      public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
        int status, Bundle extras) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
     }


 private GeoPoint getPoint(int lat, int lon) {

     return(new GeoPoint(lat, lon));

     /*
        return(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1000000.0),
                              (int)(lon*1000000.0)));
                           */
      }
  private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
        private List<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Drawable marker=null;
        private OverlayItem inDrag=null;
        private ImageView dragImage=null;
        private int xDragImageOffset=0;
        private int yDragImageOffset=0;
        private int xDragTouchOffset=0;
        private int yDragTouchOffset=0;

        public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker, int lat, int longitude) {
          super(marker);
          this.marker=marker;

          dragImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drag);
          xDragImageOffset=dragImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()/2;
          yDragImageOffset=dragImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

          items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(lat,
                                              longitude),
                                    "UN", "United Nations"));

          /*
          items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.76866299974387,
                                              -73.98268461227417),
                                    "Lincoln Center",
                                    "Home of Jazz at Lincoln Center"));
           */
          populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
          return(items.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
                          boolean shadow) {
          super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

          boundCenterBottom(marker);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
          return(items.size());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
          final int action=event.getAction();
          final int x=(int)event.getX();
          final int y=(int)event.getY();
          boolean result=false;

          if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            for (OverlayItem item : items) {
              Point p=new Point(0,0);

              myMapView.getProjection().toPixels(item.getPoint(), p);

              if (hitTest(item, marker, x-p.x, y-p.y)) {
                result=true;
                inDrag=item;
                items.remove(inDrag);
                populate();

                xDragTouchOffset=0;
                yDragTouchOffset=0;

                setDragImagePosition(p.x, p.y);
                dragImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                xDragTouchOffset=x-p.x;
                yDragTouchOffset=y-p.y;

                break;
              }
            }
          }
          else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && inDrag!=null) {
            setDragImagePosition(x, y);
            result=true;
          }
          else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && inDrag!=null) {
            dragImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            GeoPoint pt=myMapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x-xDragTouchOffset,
                                                       y-yDragTouchOffset);


            String title = inDrag.getTitle();
            OverlayItem toDrop=new OverlayItem(pt, title,
                                               inDrag.getSnippet());

            items.add(toDrop);
            populate();
            double lat = pt.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;

            double lon = pt.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

            ArrayList<Double> passing = new ArrayList<Double>();
            passing.add(lat);
            passing.add(lon);

            Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
            ReverseGeocodeLookupTask task = new ReverseGeocodeLookupTask();
            task.applicationContext = context;
            task.activityContext = rescue.this; 
            task.execute(passing);

            //CenterLocatio(pt);
            inDrag=null;
            result=true;
          }

          return(result || super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
        }

        private void setDragImagePosition(int x, int y) {
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)dragImage.getLayoutParams();

          lp.setMargins(x-xDragImageOffset-xDragTouchOffset,
                          y-yDragImageOffset-yDragTouchOffset, 0, 0);
          dragImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
      }

  public class ReverseGeocodeLookupTask extends AsyncTask <ArrayList<Double>, Void, String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected Context applicationContext;
        protected Context activityContext;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activityContext, "Please wait", 
                    "Requesting location", true);
        }


        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<Double>... params) 
        {


            String foundAddress = "";
            String localityName = "";
            ArrayList<Double> passed = params[0];
            double lat = passed.get(0);
            double lon = passed.get(1);
            try
            {

            List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(applicationContext,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(lat,lon, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                String addressLine = "";

                for(Integer i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                {
                    if(!addressLine.equals(""))
                    {
                        addressLine+= ", ";
                    }

                    addressLine+=  addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                }

                if(addressLine!="")
                {
                    foundAddress+= addressLine;
                }
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
            finally
            {
            }
            return foundAddress;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            this.dialog.cancel();
            showToast(result);

        }
    }

  public void showToast(String message)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String toasttext = message;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toasttext, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
      }
```

thanks for ideas

here is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/rescue_rel_layout"
android:gravity="top" android:background="#fff">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" android:id="@+id/rescue_top_control_bar"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:gravity="center_vertical">



    <TextView android:id="@+id/rescueText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Where are you ?" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#1D0073"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />



</RelativeLayout>



<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/rescue_top_control_bar"

    android:orientation="vertical">





    <RelativeLayout     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >

      <RelativeLayout     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

          <RelativeLayout     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >     

     <com.google.android.maps.MapView

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:foregroundGravity="top"
             android:apiKey=""
             android:clickable="true"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:id="@+id/rescueMapView"
             />

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/drag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/marker_up"
        android:visibility="gone"
      /> 


     </RelativeLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/loader" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >



        </LinearLayout>         

     </RelativeLayout>




    </RelativeLayout>    


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Post the relevant code only.

Comment: The code above is the one that I am using .. There are no any other errors.. Everything displayed except the maps itself

Comment: Type safety : A generic array of ArrayList<Double> is created for a varargs parameter  . The local variable location is never read. The local variable myGeoPoint is never read . The local variable localityName is never read .. These are some warnings that I get..

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own key first. Also there are some other setting to follow. Here is a nice toutorial-> [Google map v2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

2 Edits I suggest:

1. Inside your layout xml, use

( 4.5th step in that toutorial. activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Make your main class to extend `FragmentActivity' (4.6th step in the toutorial)

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// This line is all that you need to display a map.

    }
   }
```

Finally, the important one, AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your_package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


<permission
    android:name="your_package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your_api_key" />
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Hey the issue persists.. I have done all the steps here.. as far as I know When publishing an app to market we create our own unique key. Here we are using debug.keystore and I generated a new API key from the console then add to manifest file but still the same..

Comment: Instead of repairing the current project, create a new one. Before that, I'll say 2 more suggestions.

Comment: No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children 
 are added dynamically. This is the error that I get when I tried to add android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment". Where do I need to add this in layout xml ? Currently I've tried under this tag:<com.google.android.maps.MapView

Comment: I've also added layout xml

Comment: What you tried is Google map v1. It's KEY generation is stopped by google. You have to use Map v2 as in that toutorial, with my 2 edits.

Comment: I think you got the issue the I've to use mapv2 but because of source code is so complicated I couldn't implement it..

Comment: Actially v2 is simpler than v1. Be careful about manifest(here you give your key). I'm updating answer with source code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turn on the Google Maps Android API v2 from your console? many people forget to turn it.
Select Services on left side and turn on Google Maps Android API v2[image]